# LaTeX not finding packages after TexHash

Tags: packages, installing

I'm running Debian Jessie and my LaTeX was running smoothly until I replaced one of the packages in `/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/...` and ran `texhash`. It seemed to succeed, but...

Now, LaTeX cannot find ANY of the packages in that folder (or anywhere else in `/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/`, whether I run `latex` or `pdflatex`).

Has this happened to anyone else before? Does anyone know what the problem may be?

Thanks in advance.

Note: `/usr/local/share/texmf/ls-R` contains the packages which LaTeX cannot find, and when I run texhash, the first line it shows is:

```
texhash: Updating /usr/local/share/texmf/ls-R...
```

Comment: Take a look at `/usr/local/share/texmf/ls-R` file.  Is it readable?  Does it have the list of files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A wild guess:  try as a root

```
chmod -R a+r /usr/local/share/texmf/
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know what caused the permissions on that folder to change, but it looks like that was it.